# TAILS OS on New Hard drive

Tags: tails

Aplologies for amateurish question.

I have a Windows laptop with no O/S installed on hard drive.
I have a MacBook, can I download a Windows version of TAILS on MacBook to boot up my Windows laptop?

Comment: Your question is so confusing.